# Putting labels into quotation marks when describing a graph

Tags: academic-writing, quotation-marks

Suppose we want to describe the following graph.

[image]

Isn't it preferable to put labels in quotation marks?

For example, instead of writing

> 1 Salaries comprise three-thirds of the total budget, as opposed to building and transportation and technology, whose participation proportions are 17% and 8%, respectively.

can we write:

> 2 "Salaries" comprises three-thirds of the total budget, as opposed to "building and transportation" and "technology", whose participation proportions are 17% and 8%, respectively.

I thinks since the category label "buildings and transport" have an "and" inside it, it is absolutely more suitable to put all category labels in quotation marks.

Two complimentary questions:

(1) Should We put all labels in quotation marks or not put any of them in quotation marks throughout a piece of writing? In other words, is putting some of them in quotation marks and leave some of them without quotation marks a bad writing style?

For example:

> 3 Salaries comprise three-thirds of the total budget, as opposed to "building and transportation" and "technology", whose participation proportions are 17% and 8%, respectively.

(2) When putting category labels in quotation marks, should we always refer to them by singular verbs regardless of the plurality of the label itself?

For example is it correct to write:

> 4 Salaries comprise ...

> 5 "Salaries" comprises ...

Answer (score 1):

No.

Using quotation marks would be taken to imply that you are using 'xxxx' because others use the term but you do not necessarily agree it is correct.

e.g. "John was very pleased with the 'help' he had given". John thinks he had been helpful, but the writer disagrees.

It's inappropriate for labelling a graph.

Comment: I don't think so. Actually my question is a follow up on this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173204/can-quotation-marks-be-used-when-describing-the-contents-of-a-label

Comment: +1 In several decades reading scientific English I have never ever seen anyone using quotation marks in this context.

Comment: "I don't think so". What do you mean by that? Are you saying that you asked the question, but will only accept an affirmative answer?